# Transformer Model LTspice - Flyback Voltage Clamped on Primary but Still Present on Secondary Side

Tags: transformer, ltspice, inductor, simulation, flyback

I'm simulating a circuit in LTspice using a pulse transformer to drive a JFET gate. The circuit is supposed to work as follows: We drive M1 (N channel FET) to pulse current from a 20V source through a 50uH Primary winding P1. This creates a positive voltage at the dot of P1. Current appears on the secondary side, with positive current travelling into the gate of the JFET. The positive voltage at the Dot of the Secondary winding S1 puts a Zener diode into breakdown, which would ideally be sized such that the positive voltage at S1 is cancelled by the Zener to put 0V on the JFET, keeping it 'ON' or conducting.

[image: Schematic]

The problem is that, when the drive pulse for M1 has a falling edge, the current in the Primary winding quickly disappears, which would create a high voltage (what I am calling the flyback voltage) in the reverse direction, negative V at the dot of P1. To prevent this I have a schottky diode across the winding P1 to clamp the flyback voltage to 400mV. But the voltage on the secondary is still reversing polarity (going negative at S1 Dot) when the primary current goes to 0 when M1 shuts off. This negative voltage on S1 forward biases the Zener Diode and can discharge the gate enough to turn the JFET OFF. So the Falling edge of the Turn-On Signal is causing a spurious turn-OFF of the JFET.

It seems like there is a problem with my model, because if the primary voltage is clamped in the reverse direction (when current is being removed), shouldn't the secondary voltage be prevented from going so far below ground? The coupled inductors of the transformer are perfectly coupled, so thinking about V = N * d(PHI)/dt, the voltages on the primary and secondary should be equal to each other. So clamping the primary flyback should have done what I expected, limiting the Voltage reversal on the Secondary. Why is this not working as expected? Is my thinking fundamentally flawed in some way? Any advice or insight into problems with my model or suggestions to make this circuit work as needed is greatly appreciated. Please note that the coupled inductors have a series resistance of 1ohm.

[image: Waveforms]
The waveforms on the bottom pane are drive signal for M1 in blue and Voltage across P1 in Green. As expected, when M1 is conducting the voltage on the primary is positive at the Dot. When M1 shuts off, the P1 voltage is prevented from going Negative at the dot because of the clamping diode D3.

The 2 waveforms on the top pane are the secondary side signals, Secondary output at Dot in Red, and JFET Gate Voltage in light blue. It is clear that when M1 shuts off, the voltage at S1 Dot goes negative, which puts a negative voltage on the gate, having the opposite effect of the intended turn-ON signal.

Comment: That's quite a low inductance for a GDT. But what are its resistances? Why would you want a GDT to drive a DC-biased JFET anyway?

Comment: @Tim Williams - Trying to keep the inductance Low because the overall power needed to charge/discharge the JFET gate is very small. The series resistance for each Inductor was 1ohm. Removing that seems to fix this issue of the secondary voltage going negative. Can you elaborate on your question? If you are asking, why am I trying to drive the JFET gate to 0V when it is already 0V at startup, I'm just trying to prove in the functionality that the circuit can deliver positive voltage to the secondary side. Eventually I will add a 2nd primary winding with opposite polarity and another NMOS

Comment: to drive the Secondary negative, turning OFF the JFET. Then I will be able to pulse an "ON" or "OFF" Signal through the GDT (signals will have to be regularly sent thru the transformer to 'refresh' the charge on the gate) to put the JFET into whatever state is needed.

Comment: You're trying to push through a transformer, a signal with a DC offset. The baseline or center is 6V, not 0V. Measure current in the transformer, it's ratcheting up, quite rapidly in fact.  This doesn't seem like a good way to minimize "overall power". Note that magnetizing inductance of an ideal transformer is infinite, not zero :)

Comment: I'm not trying to push the 12V signal through the transformer. The 12V signal controls the gate of a FET. The FET controls the amount of current that is allowed to flow thru the primary winding from the 20V Source. As the FET Turns on, a very large di/dt is seen by the Primary and so a medium Voltage (V = L(di/dt)) is produced across its terminals. This energy is then coupled to the secondary in such a way that a positive voltage produced at the Secondary which keeps the JFET 'ON'. This is a simulation and I'm not trying to optimize power but really just see if this concept is worth building.

Comment: Sorry, 20V. So half that or 10V DC. Point stands. There is a correct way to do transformer coupling however (look up "DC restore" circuits).